# root privilege with su

Tags: android, root

I am using su , busybox on android device. 
but on doing "su", it seems that I have no root privilege:

```
shell@nemo:/ $ su
1|shell@nemo:/ $

1|shell@nemo:/ $ whoami
shell
shell@nemo:/ $
```

**EDIT1**:

Seems like the privileged in su are OK. please see below , from adb shell: shell@nemo:/system/xbin $ ls -al su -rwxr-xr-x root root 75364 2015-11-21 13:10

**EDIT2**:

I've set 7777 permission (suid), but it still fails.

```
chmod 7777 su-arm

 shell@nemo:/ $ ls -al /system/xbin/su-arm
-rwsrwsrwt root     shell      467952 2016-11-20 12:01 su-arm
shell@nemo:/ $ su-arm
255|shell@nemo:/ $ id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=2000(shell),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0
shell@nemo:/ $whoami
shell
```

**EDIT3:**
I've updated su binary and busybox binary, but each now fails differently:

```
shell@nemo:/ $ busybox su
su: unknown user root
1|shell@nemo:/ $ su
error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.
1|shell@nemo:/ $
```

How can I understand what's wrong with su and how to fix it ?

Thanks,
Ranchu

Comment: Do you actually have a need for super user privileges?  If so, then have you tried running those commands?

Comment: Yes, I have a true need for that. How can I start understanding what's wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to install "su" with root privilege.

Just copy su with normal user privilege doesn't mean "rooting device".

I think your question should be something like "how can i root my device?"

Comment: Right, I try to root a device. 
I have normal privileged in su. please see below , from adb shell:
shell@nemo:/system/xbin $ ls -al su
-rwxr-xr-x root     root        75364 2015-11-21 13:10 su

Comment: As i see your su binary is not SUID, that's the reason you are not able to run a root shell.

Comment: How can you see that. trying now with another build from Supersu, I get still another error: shell@nemo:/ $ su
error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.
1|shell@nemo:/ $

Comment: getting the latest release of su (superuser-r259.zip) from https://superuser.phh.me/, I still get same behaviour.

Comment: I have set suid permssion (chmod 7777), but it still fails. ls -al /system/xbin/su-arm
-rwsrwsrwt root     shell      467952 2016-11-20 12:01 su-arm
shell@nemo:/ $ su-arm
255|shell@nemo:/ $. I've edit the message.

Comment: Run "su" and after run "id" command,  please paste the output

Comment: even su-arm --help return 255, That's strange.

Comment: on using busybox, I get better response, but still fails: 130|shell@nemo:/ $ busybox su
su: unknown user root
1|shell@nemo:/ $

Answer (score 1):

`busybox` `su` is looking for the `root` user in `/etc/passwd`. On my android device this file does not exist. You can create a dummy `root` entry by simply running

```
echo 'root:x:0:0:root:/root:/system/bin/sh' > /etc/passwd
```

after this, `su` is happy.